# UITextView shouldChangeTextInRange incorrect for Romaji keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, romaji

So I've noticed some bugs in my app, as I'm trying to use the `shouldChangeTextInRange` delegate of the UITextView to allow for simple things like in-line mentions.  However, I've noticed for any keyboard that is multi-stage keyboard (such as the Romaji keyboard for Japanese), the delegate does not get called when it performs a replacement of characters.  I have this simple setup to demonstrate:

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    print("length: \(range.length) start: \(range.location)")
    print(text)
    
    return true;
}
```

Using the Romaji keyboard I type 'ka', the textbox shows 'か', but the prints from the delegate show:

> length: 0 start: 0 k
>
> length: 0 start: 1 a

So the textview has replaced characters without calling the delegate.  This seems like a broken feature to me, as it completely breaks my mention functionality.  Has anyone run into this before?  It's most evident in this keyboard, but any multi-stage keyboard exhibits the same behavior.  I could use the didChange delegate instead, but it gives far less information and makes the feature a lot harder to program in.

Am I missing something here, is there any trick to actually catching these edits in the delegate?

Comment: Have you solved this?, i am facing same issue

Comment: I opened a bug with apple that never went anywhere.  I ended up having to combine the info from both keyboard delegate methods to get it working, was very messy, and at my past job so I can't give much more info sorry.